# convert list into int array

Tags: java, arrays, list, shuffle

i want get back the shuffled array of type integer, so i wrote this code but its not working... in this code i want new value each time of every object of class Scase... but that must from 5,50,100...

```
class Scase {

    int label;
    int value;

    public static int arr[] = {5,50,100};

    public static int[] toarr(List<Integer> list)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
            ret[i] = list.get(i);
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scase obj[] = new Scase[1];
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        lst = Arrays.asList(arr);

        Collections.shuffle(lst);

        int ar[];
        ar = toarr(lst);

        for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            obj[i].value = ar[i];
        }
        System.out.println(obj[0].label + "  " + obj[0].value);
        System.out.println(obj[1].label + "  " + obj[1].value);
        System.out.println(obj[2].label + "  " + obj[2].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the language (C#? Java? ...?) you are using. Also, is this about the list-array-conversion or about shuffling? You may want to revise your question title.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there really is a better way of doing this due to the nature of Java's handling of primitive types, boxing, arrays and generics. In particular:

`List<T>.toArray` won't work because there's no conversion from Integer to `int`
You can't use `int` as a type argument for generics, so it would have to be an int-specific method (or one which used reflection to do nasty trickery).
I believe there are libraries which have autogenerated versions of this kind of method for all the primitive types (i.e. there's a template which is copied for each type). It's ugly, but that's the way it is I'm afraid :(

Even though the Arrays class came out before generics arrived in Java, it would still have to include all the horrible overloads if it were introduced today (assuming you want to use primitive arrays).